# Generate changes script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Let's imagine I added new column for some table in SQL Server Management Studio. Is there any way to get change script which is executed when I press save?

What I want to achieve is to apply the same change to other databases (we have a separate database for each developer for debuggin purposes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are using table designer in MS SSMS.

Do the changes in the designer and just before hitting `Save`, go to the `Table Designer` menu and select `Generate Change Script...`.